Bacula Console Unknown term code
Bacula Community - Version: 15.0.2 (21 March 2024) x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-bacula ubuntu 22.04
The bacula log has the following warnings/errors(?) after every catalog backup job (the catalog backup job itself with the correct JobID successfully completed):
****-dir JobId 0: Automatically selected Catalog: BackupDB
****-dir JobId 0: Using Catalog "BackupDB"
****-dir JobId 0: Using Catalog "BackupDB"
****-dir JobId 0: No Volumes found to perform the command

.
There is no any backup job listed with the JobID 0. I had initially problems with this new version of bacula and upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (which killed my previous bacula backup completely). But it was fixed and I had, of course, the backup job with the ID 0 which failed then, but it was deleted.
It happens only when the catalog backup job is completed.
"Bacula: Console Unknown term code " is the subject of the email message sent by:
 mailcommand = "/opt/bacula/bin/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \<email address\>\" -s \"Bacula: %t %e of %c %l\" %r" 

How can I find the source of that JobId 0 error/warning message?
